# How to copy filtered data in new excel file

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

How can I `save as`/`export` filtered data to new `excel` file.

filtered data means, I have applied few filters on my working sheet. Now I need new file of it.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way probably is to copy your data to a new workbook.

- press CTRL+A (this will select all visible cells)

  - (if you have a table (created by insert - table) then you might need to press CTRL+A twice to select the header too)
- press CTRL+C to copy
- CTRL+V in the new workbook

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the advanced filtering function to copy the filtered content to another place.

In the worksheet, click the menu "Data" "Filter" "Advanced Filter".

In the advanced filter window, select "Copy to another location"

[image]